# Phalcon 2 output flash with twig template

Tags: twig, phalcon

I'm using twig as the template engine, works good, but I'm having an issue outputing the flash messages there. none of these show anything.

`{{ this.flash.output() }}`

Only `{{ content }}` works, but it outputs notice and php warning messages as well.

This is how I set the flash

```
$di->set('flash', function () {
    $flash = new FlashDirect([
      //tie in with twitter bootstrap classes
      'error'     => 'alert alert-danger',
      'success'   => 'alert alert-success',
      'notice'    => 'alert alert-info',
      'warning'   => 'alert alert-warning'
    ]);

    return $flash;
});
```

This how I pass the messages to flash

```
$this->flash->error('Please use the link sent to you by email');
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: was able to fix it using {{ content }} instead of {{ flash.output() }}

Answer (score 0):

You output flash messages in Volt like: (without the `this`)

```
{{ flash.output() }}
```

And you output flash messages in PHP like:

```
<?php echo $this->flash->output(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm using twig template engine, the {{ flash.output() }} doesn't work, and in twig you can't use php code directly

Comment: How exactly you are using this twig templates ? Show us your engine class for phalcon. As soon as twig engine extends Injectable code from this answer should work totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a redirect?

If so you need flashSession.